# I have a link to a .mp4 file I want to download. But before I download it I want it compressed. Any advice?

Tags: python, html, compression, mp4

I managed to get my code to download a full video(.mp4) from a link. However, the type of videos will vary in size, usually around 2-3GB.  I would prefer to compress the video prior to downloading it.  Is there a way to do this inside of the python script? I believe the video will be 1080p.  Something around 720p with little audio loss would be great.

I have read about ffmpeg as a Linux command, but that's not what I'm looking for.

```
print("MP4 Link")
print(downloadMP4)

# Download
print("Beginning file download")
wget.download(downloadMP4, "/home/user/Downloads/name")#Removed actual destination
print("Done")
exit()
```

Comment: You cannot compress the file before downloading it unless you control the server.

Comment: How would you expect the videos to get re-encoded on the server? Do you have shell access to it?

Comment: He **could** use some sort of cloud converting service, though. I think that might be the only option. Even though it won't make the job as a whole faster, it might save some bandwidth at the machine running the downloader script.

Comment: @astrocode I have no further knowledge on which services might do this, but I think it's worth the search. As I said, it won't make things faster, since you'll be making this into a three-step process of downloading-compressing-downloading, but your primary server could save some stress.

Answer (score 1):

Try using cloudconvert @ https://cloudconvert.com
With the API you can compress a file before downloading it. I hope this helps